# Node with two different voltages at the same time - Two branches (voltage source+resistor) in parallel - LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I simulated the following circuit:

[image]

Why is Vu=7.5 V? I expect there to be an error because Vu=5=10 at the same time.

The current in the two branches is the same, thus (R1=R2):

$$Vu=R_1 i+V_1$$

$$Vu=R_1 i+V_2$$

$$V_1=5=V_2=10$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know KCL ?

Comment: Hello @LongPham see edit please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equations are incorrect. If you define the current in one way, then that current needs to be negative for the other side.

$$\begin{align}
V_u &= R\cdot i + V_1 \\
V_u &= -R\cdot i + V_2 \\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
R\cdot i &= V_u - V_1 \\
R\cdot i &= V_2 - V_u
\end{align}$$

You find that

$$V_u = \frac{V_1 + V_2}{2}$$